# Windows DPDK L2fwd- Receiving packets out of sequence

Tags: network-programming, dpdk

I am validating DPDK receive functionality & for this I'm shooting a pcap externally &
added code in l2fwd to dump received packets to pcap, the l2fwd dumped pcap have all the packets from shooter but some of them are not in sequence.
Shooter is already validated.

DPDK version in use-21.11

link of the pcap used : https://wiki.wireshark.org/uploads/__moin_import__/attachments/SampleCaptures/tcp-ecn-sample.pcap
Out of order packets are random. For the first run I saw no jumbled packets but was able to replicate the issue on second run with the 2nd,3rd,4th packets jumbled having order 3,4,2.

Below is snipped from l2fwd example & our modifications as //TESTCODE..

```
/* Read packet from RX queues. 8< */
for (i = 0; i < qconf->n_rx_port; i++) { 
            portid = qconf->rx_port_list[i];
            nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(portid, 0,
                                            pkts_burst, MAX_PKT_BURST); 
            port_statistics[portid].rx += nb_rx; 
            for (j = 0; j < nb_rx; j++) {
                            m = pkts_burst[j];
                            // TESTCODE_STARTS
                            uint8_t* pkt = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, uint8_t*);
                            dump_to_pcap(pkt, rte_pktmbuf_pkt_len(m));
                            // TESTCODE_ENDS
                            rte_prefetch0(rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, void *));
                            l2fwd_simple_forward(m, portid);
                          } 
}
/* >8 End of read packet from RX queues. */
```

Below is code for `dump_to_pcap`

```
static int
dump_to_pcap(uint8_t* pkt, int pkt_len)
{

static FILE* fp = NULL;
static int init_file = 0;
if (0 == init_file) {

printf("Creating pcap\n");
char pcap_filename[256] = { 0 };
char Two_pcap_filename[256] = { 0 };
currentDateTime(pcap_filename);

sprintf(Two_pcap_filename,".\\Rx_%d_%s.pcap", 0, pcap_filename);
printf("FileSName to Create: %s\n", Two_pcap_filename);

fp = fopen(Two_pcap_filename, "wb");
if (NULL == fp) {
    printf("Unable to open file\n");
    fp = NULL;
}
else {
    printf("File create success..\n");
    init_file = 1;

    typedef struct pcap_file_header1 {
    unsigned int  magic; // a 32-bit "magic number"
    unsigned short version_major; //a 16-bit major version number
    unsigned short version_minor; //a 16-bit minor version number
    unsigned int thiszone; //a 32-bit "time zone offset" field that's actually not used, so ou can (and probably should) just make it 0
    unsigned int sigfigs;  //a 32-bit "time stamp accuracy" field that's not actually used,so you can (and probably should) just make it 0;
    unsigned int snaplen;  //a 32-bit "snapshot length" field
    unsigned int linktype; //a 32-bit "link layer type" field
    }dumpFileHdr;

    dumpFileHdr file_hdr;
    file_hdr.magic = 2712847316; //0xa1b2c3d4;
    file_hdr.version_major = 2; 
    file_hdr.version_minor = 4; 
    file_hdr.thiszone = 0;
    file_hdr.sigfigs = 0;
    file_hdr.snaplen = 65535;
    file_hdr.linktype = 1;
    fwrite((void*)(&file_hdr), sizeof(dumpFileHdr), 1, fp);
    //printf("Pcap Header written\n");
}
}

typedef struct pcap_pkthdr1 {
unsigned int ts_sec;      /* time stamp */
unsigned int ts_usec;
unsigned int caplen;     /* length of portion present */
unsigned int len;        /* length this packet (off wire) */
}dumpPktHdr;

dumpPktHdr pkt_hdr;
static int ts_sec = 1;
pkt_hdr.ts_sec = ts_sec++;
pkt_hdr.ts_usec = 0;
pkt_hdr.caplen = pkt_hdr.len = pkt_len;

if (NULL != fp) {
fwrite((void*)(&pkt_hdr), sizeof(dumpPktHdr), 1, fp);
fwrite((void*)(pkt), pkt_len, 1, fp);
fflush(fp);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain or share some packet are out of sequence, Please update with details NIC used and l2fwd arguments (this will help to reproduce the issue). I am assuming you are using 1 queue too.

Comment: Packets are out of Sequence in the pcap that I am receiving(from dump) as compared to the one I sent(using shooter). There are 100 packets in the pcap, I am receiving all the packets but some are jumbled. I am using 1 queue.
NIC used : Mellanox Connectx-6Dx
l2fwd arguments : dpdk-l2fwd.exe -l 1,2 -n 1 -- -p 0x3 -q 1 -P

Comment: thanks for the update, please update the ticket with `1. link to download the PCAP to be used, 2. which sequence of packets are seen to out of order 3. can I reproduce the same with packeth, tcpreplay or dpdk-pktgen`?

Comment: Thanks @VipinVarghese for taking interest in the matter.  1. link to download the pcap https://wiki.wireshark.org/uploads/__moin_import__/attachments/SampleCaptures/tcp-ecn-sample.pcap  2. Out of order packets are random. For the first run I saw no jumbled packets but was able to replicate the issue on second run with the 2,3,4 packets jumbled having order 3,4,2.      3. I am using proprietary pcap shooter & I have validated shooter's pcap sequencing with parallel setup. If packeth, tcpreplay or dpdk-pktgen are maintaining the packet sequence then you can reproduce the scenario.

Comment: you have not shared code snippet for `dump_to_pcap`. hence requesting you to share code snippet which will help to easily print/compare the sequence id for the packets to identify mismatch. With the current pcap I am unable to figure out (without pcap capture) to identify the random ordering. Please update

Comment: Added code for `dump_to_pcap` . For out of order packets you will need to compare the input pcap and dump pcap either manually in wireshark or by using any utility.

Comment: Thanks @stackinside for helping. Yes, the transmitter side also has one Tx queue. I want to receive the packets in the same order. You say packets can be reordered by transmitter. How can I stop this reordering of packets?

Comment: @srg please note, checking the code base for DPDK pcap burst replay software uses `rte_eth_tx_burst(ctx->tx_port_id, (tx_queue++ % NB_TX_QUEUES), &(mbuf[index + total_sent]), to_sent - total_sent);`. Similarly `proprietary pcap shooter` could be sending using multiple tx queues. I am using `tcpreplay, dpdk-ptgen with 1 tx queue` on recieve side I am using `your code and dpdk_pdump with 1 RX queue` to reproduce

Comment: @VipinVarghese I used Mellanox Management Tool "Mlx5Cmd.exe -Sniffer" to check received packets. I received all packets in the correct order here. So there is a problem with the DPDK example "l2fwd". Regarding DPDK-dumpcap and pdump, these are not supported on windows.

Comment: @srg interesting as I am unable to produce the error in lInux using DPDK-PDUMP. Hence this requires proper debugging (windows env). If you are available we can have live debug to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: @srg waiting for your update as I don't have server 2091 to run dpdk in windows. Will require live debug to isolate if it's l2fwd or dpdk pmd from mellanox

Comment: @VipinVarghese Live debugging won't be possible on the setup I have access to.

Comment: @srg thanks for the update, I am still waiting for a windows server 2019 to be made available to reproduce this.

Comment: @VipinVarghese. Were you able to replicate the issue?

Comment: @srg thanks for the reminder, as mentioned I did not have windows server 2019 hence requested for live debug. I have managed a system with connectx d6 card, Will you be available for a live debug to reproduce?

Comment: @VipinVarghese While sending packets at 1 packet per milli-sec, the packets are received in order. Increasing the speed causes more and more packets to be out of order. Try replicating it with speed greater than 15 packets per milli-sec. And yes, we can connect for a live debug.

Comment: @srg thanks for the pointer. I will change this to your requirement `send multi burst of packet`. Question `could it be the sender which is causing packet reorder`. To rule this out `set burst from 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128`. This will help in reproducing the error is at sender or not

Comment: @VipinVarghese Update: Facing a similar issue while Receiving Packets at Mellanox Management Tool `Mlx5Cmd.exe -Sniffer`. Sending at ( bursts of ) 1, 2, 4 pkts/milli sec there were no out of order pkts. But when sending speed is greater than 8 pkts/ milli sec, there is increase in out of order packets. To validate shooter, in same h/w setup mirrored traffic to another proprietary card which was was able to receive all packets in order, even at much higher speeds. Seems like a problem at Mellanox Adaptor. Is there some settings/configurations I can tweak to fix this?

Comment: did you get a chance to further debug the issue on MLX cards? Di you try to do 1 RX and 1 TX as burst count?

Comment: are there any follow-up information on this? FYI, if pcie relaxed ordering is disabled in Linux I am not able to get the issue. Can you please check if PCIe relaxed ordering can be disabled for Mellanox NIC in windows and retry again?

Comment: Hello! Have u resolved the out-of-sequence problem ?